# How would I make a packet sniffer in python?

Tags: python, scapy, eof, packet-sniffers, sniffing

I used a code snippet from stackoverflow, I can't find the post now, but this is what it was

```
from scapy.all import *
sniff(filter="192.168.1.25", prn=lambda x:x.sprintf("{IP:%IP.src% -> %IP.dst%\n}")
```

I'm getting an unexpected EOF while parsing

I don't know much about scapy, nor socket. I have no idea how to approach it. Can anyone provide a working example below? I've looked all over and was unable to find one, and this topic has been dead for years

I'm not really willing to learn socket/scapy, just want an example, something temporary, so if socket is the best, post below

Comment: you are handling the method of  wrong,try creating an object then do your lambda function to see your error

Comment: the person who wrote the code missed a ), got another error

`ImportError: cannot import name 'NPCAP_PATH' from 'scapy.arch.pcapdnet'`

Comment: what is your python version

Comment: Python 3.7.0 is my python version

Answer (score 0):

this was a known Issue a year ago, try upgrading pip ,then reinstall scapy using

`pip install scapy --upgrade` if this doesn't cut it.

Download the developer version https://github.com/secdev/scapy/archive/master.zip you might run into different errors but this fixes you current error.

Comment: `Requirement already up-to-date: scapy in c:\users\Administrator\appdata\local\programs\py
thon\python37\lib\site-packages (2.4.2)`

Unfortunately that hasn't resolved anything :/

Comment: ok remove the one you currently have and download the developer version, I personally use it with no errors

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
from scapy.sendrecv import sniff

sniff(filter="192.168.1.25", prn=lambda x: x.sprintf("{IP:%IP.src% -> %IP.dst%\n}"))
```

Comment: i have three different errors, but i've come to a resolution kind of, i still have an error though
if i use `from scapy.all import *` i get an import error
if i use `from scapy import *` i get "sniff" isnt defined error

im using just `import scapy` and i'm getting 
`AttributeError: module 'scapy' has no attribute 'sniff'`

(explained in here, [https://pastebin.com/TNfx2F8P]

Comment: also, when i use your code, i get this error:
`ImportError: cannot import name 'NPCAP_PATH' from 'scapy.arch.pcapdnet'`

i tried changing the imports and still got the same errors, sniff isnt defined

Answer (score 0):

The above post was correct, this was fixed ages ago. please update against the RC versions:

```
pip install scapy --pre --upgrade
```

Note: the `--pre` enables RC versions